# Net::HTTP follow maximum of three redirects?

Tags: ruby

I have this method in my class:

```
def self.get(url)
  #TODO We could test with https too
  if url.match(/^http/)
    correct_url = url
  else
    correct_url = "http://#{url}"
  end

  uri = URI.parse(correct_url)

  if uri.respond_to? 'request_uri'
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    http.request(request)
  else
    puts "Incorrect URI"
  end
end
```

Unfortunately it's not following the redirects.

Can someone tell me how to make this method allow a maximum of three redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def self.get(url)
  # TODO: test with https too
  url = "http://#{url}" unless url.match(/^http/)

  3.times do 
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    if uri.respond_to?(:request_uri)
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      case response.code
      when '301', '302'
        url = response.header['location']
      else
        return response
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But don't you think your code will send request 3 times even when it get successful response on the first attempt?

Comment: No: `return response` returns the response immediately when its `code` does not match `301` or `302`.